# How to Add Mat UI to child components in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, web-frontend

I created child component to route when a button click and the routing is working perfectly. Now I want to use material ui to a form in that child component but mat ui styles aren't adding to child component. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Adding angular material

   ng add @angular/material
2. Adding Material Components

In your IDE navigate to the file “src/app/app.module.ts”, and import the following modules:

```
import { MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatSelectModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

3. And then add them to the imports array:

   imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   FormsModule,
   MatInputModule,
   MatButtonModule,
   MatSelectModule,
   MatIconModule
   ],
4. The next step is to add it your components.

Also if you have that child component in a separate module make sure to import mat components to that module as well.